# How can I keep the test cases even if there is an error? in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am using Selenium+Robot framework. When the error occurs any line of the code, the rest of the lines are not working. I want to continue and run all lines even if there is an error.
The only solution I could find was to add "Run Keyword And Continue On Failure" before all keywords. But this is very difficult.
**eg: Run Keyword And Continue On Failure click element id:words**

How can I do this in a short way without typing in all lines?

Comment: Make proxy function with try-except to run it

Comment: thank you but I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With robot framework 4.1 and newer you can set a tag to tell robot to continue on failures. This is the example in the user guide:

```
Test 2
    [Tags]    robot:continue-on-failure
    Should be Equal   1   2
    User Keyword 2
```

In this example, `User Keyword 2` will run after the previous keyword fails.

For more information see [Continue on failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#continue-on-failure) in the [Robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html)

Comment: thanks, you are great :)